# Use an Image or using the graphic function for 2D game dev?

Tags: qt, graphics

I'm trying to write a simple game that has some dogs and cats move around. Now my dogs, cats is the read and blue rectangle, I need to make them more pretty and now is 2 options for me:

1. Using an Image.
2. Draw them by some graphic class.

But I not sure what should I choose!

1. If use Image, I must draw some (the object can animate). But it make thing simple.
2. Use graphic function give me more power (like in case there more than just dog and cat, OO will help me alot). But I will make my barin hurt.

And the the most important is which is faster?
BTW I'm using Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd most definitely use a bitmap.

Rendering a bitmap image is usually faster because it can be fully cached in memory unless it's large (which it shouldn't be, in your case). The underlying mechanics would simply involve a blazingly-fast `memcpy` (or the like) once it's been read from the disk.

Drawing a dog using vector graphics would incur a large overhead in terms of performance due to function calls, math/transformations, *and* would end up effectively needing **more** memory than a bitmap.

Comment: So, what image extensions you will use?